# Drop down doesn't appear correctly in the html page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to show an input and a drop down list. However for some reason, input appears on the page but the drop down doesn't appear properly. Here is the code below

Here is the screenshot below

[image]

As you can see, input appears fine but not the drop down. What is the problem?

```js
let card = ""
card += "<div class='container'>"
card += "<div class='row'>"
card += "<input type='text'"
card += '<select> <option value="time">A</option> <option value="place">B</option> <option value="fee">Fee</option></select>'

card += "</div>"
card += "</div>"

document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = card
```

```html
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Comment: The `input` above is malformed, you need to close the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this:

`card += "<input type='text'"`

to this:

`card += "<input type='text'>"`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let card = ""
card += "<div class='container'>"
card += "<div class='row'>"
card += "<input type='text'>"
card += '<select> <option value="time">A</option> <option value="place">B</option> <option value="fee">Fee</option></select>'

card += "</div>"
card += "</div>"

document.querySelector('#app').innerHTML = card
```

```html
<div id="app">

</div>
```

Paste the above javascript code.
As mentioned above, the problem is that you didn't close the input tag, and thus everything written after it was considered inside that same tag.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  tag was not closed properly.
For html, close the input tag like **`<input type="text">`**
For xhtml, close the input tag like **`<input type="text"/>`**